# Can I apply for an extension of time to file tax return between April 15 and July 15 2020?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, extension

I can usually apply for an tax return extension before Tax day (Apr 15) however this year tax return deadline was moved to July 15 - does it mean that I can apply for an extension after Apr 15 but before July 15? IRS website it not exactly clear on this but it looks like I can actually apply after Apr 15:
https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/coronavirus-tax-relief-filing-and-payment-deadlines

> If you need more time to file after the new July 15 deadline, or to
>   file a form with a different deadline date, you may request a filing
>   extension.

Answer (score 2):

Once the IRS changed the deadline from April to July, the deadline to file the extension form also moved to July. Since we are after 15 April you can submit the completed extension application form and what you owe on or before 15 July.

[From the FAQ](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/filing-and-payment-deadlines-questions-and-answers):

> Q. What if I am unable to file my 2019 income tax return that was
> originally due on April 15, 2020, by July 15, 2020?
>
> A.  If you are an individual, you can request an automatic extension
> to file your Federal income tax return if you can’t file by the July
> 15 deadline.  The easiest and fastest way to request a filing
> extension is to electronically file Form 4868 through your tax
> professional, tax software, or using the Free File.  Businesses,
> including trusts, must file Form 7004 to request an automatic
> extension.
>
> You must request the automatic extension by July 15, 2020.  If you
> properly estimate your 2019 tax liability using the information
> available to you and file an extension form by July 15, 2020, your tax
> return will be due on October 15, 2020.  To avoid interest and
> penalties when filing your tax return after July 15, 2020, pay the tax
> you estimate as due with your extension request.  The extension only
> gives you additional time to file, it does not give you additional
> time to pay beyond July 15, 2020.  If you do not pay your taxes by
> July 15, you will be subject to interest and penalties from July 16
> until the date of payment.
>
> U.S. citizens and permanent residents with a tax home in a foreign
> country who need an extension must file Form 2350 by July 15, 2020, if
> they can’t file their 2019 income tax return by the July 15 deadline.
> They should pay their taxes by July 15 to avoid interest and
> penalties.

Note: this is only true for Federal taxes, your state may have shifted their due date differently.